# File Upload option using angular material in angular 2 application

Tags: angular

Here, I am trying to create form. On one button, I need to upload some files.
But not getting how to upload files using angular 2 material.
Please can any one suggest.

My Code is,

```
<table>
<tr>
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" url="./upload.php"></p-fileUpload>
</tr>
<tr>
<mat-checkbox>Ignore Errors</mat-checkbox>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<button mat-raised-button color="accent">Upload</button>
</td>
<td>
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="dialogRef.close()" >Cancel</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add the code you have written in attempting to implement file uploading functionality.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
<input name="file" type="file" class="inputfile" (change)="onFileChange($event)"/>
```

then you can take care of uploaded file in onFileChange function in your .ts file ...